# Examine the contents of a WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-instrumentation

I am doing some instrumentation Unit testing of an Android application. I am trying to find a way to examine the contents of a WebView. Specifically I am looking for an example for a way to determine if an HTML table has a cell that contains a particular string value. Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks 
-Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You can debug remotely as seen here:
 https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

IF you want to see your design/layout, You can set different background/text colors for body/div/tables in your webview content.

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way to programatically search it to see if it has a particular string.